# Insert...Select - getting ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, prepared-statement

When I try to execute the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (id, some_data, more_data)             
SELECT ?, ?, ? FROM dual 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM myTable WHERE id = ?)
```

I get ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column.

However, when I change my query to:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (id, some_data, more_data)             
VALUE (?, ?, ?)
```

Using *the same values*, the statement succeeds.

Note, my table contains VARCHAR2 and BLOBs. But the values for both statements are the same.

Any idea why the original failed?

Edit1:
Commenter (Romain) and a coworker suggested that I use MERGE INTO instead of INSERT...SELECT...WHERE NOT EXISTS.... Nice point, and I did - but it gives me the same issue (ORA-01461... LONG... LONG).

Edit2:
to_lob(?) on the BLOB column doesn't work as well, gives me "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected LONG BINARY got BINARY".

Comment: Looks like what you want to do could be achieved using a `MERGE` statement anyway...

Comment: Yes, a coworker just mentioned that. I would still like to know why this doesn't work though. When I use to_lob() I get "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected LONG BINARY got BINARY".

Answer (score 0):

Give us an Example with values. It works with simple values:

```
CREATE TABLE feed (Id NUMBER,   DATA VARCHAR2(30)  , data1 BLOB);
INSERT INTO feed VALUES (1, '1', '1');
INSERT INTO feed (id, DATA, data1)           
  SELECT 1, '1', '1' FROM dual  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM feed WHERE id = 1) ;
INSERT INTO feed 
   (SELECT 2, '1', '1' FROM dual  
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (     SELECT 1 FROM feed WHERE id = 3) );
Result:
SELECT * FROM feed
1   1   1   <BLOB>
2   1   1   <BLOB>
```